# Putting Linked List inside structure in C (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, structure

I have a task to make something that looks like Hotel Booking program in C.
Basically I should have 2 structures, one for reservations of rooms in the hotel (that contains information about that room like its ID, floor, how many beds are there and stuff like that, pointer to person that reserved the room and **list** of people that will be in that room) and the other structure for persons (which contains, lets say, name and surname of person).

The problem I am having is segmentation fault that I get since I probably didn't make those structures right.

Here is a part of my code, that is supposed to add a guest inside the list (that is located in reservation structure):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXSTR 25
#define FORMAT_LEN 15

typedef struct person //structure that holds info about person
{
    char name[MAXSTR + 1];
    char surname[MAXSTR + 1];
}Guest;

typedef struct persons // list of persons
{
    Guest person;
    struct persons* next;
} Persons;

typedef struct //Pointer to first person in list
{
    Persons* list;
} List;

typedef struct room //structure that holds info about rooms that are reserved
{
    unsigned int ID;
    unsigned int floor;
    unsigned int bedcount;
    struct tm dateArrival;
    struct tm dateDep;
    bool cancelled;
    unsigned int price;
    Guest* person;
    List* list;
}Reservation;

typedef struct rooms
{
    Reservation room;
    struct rooms* next;
} Reservations;

bool PutGuestInsideList(List* list);
char* EnterString(char* str);

int main()
{
    Reservations* room = NULL;
    List list = { NULL };

    printf("New guest: \n");
    if(PutGuestInsideList(room->room.list) == false)
        printf("Try again. \n");


}

bool PutGuestInsideList(List* list)
{
    if(list == NULL)
        return false;

    Persons* newpers = (Persons*) malloc(sizeof(Persons));
    if(newpers == NULL)
        return false;

    printf("Name: ");
    EnterString(newpers->person.name);
    printf("Surname: ");
    EnterString(newpers->person.surname);

    list->list = newpers;
    return true;
}
char* EnterString(char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL)
        return str;

    char format[FORMAT_LEN] = "";
    sprintf(format, "%%%u[^\n]", MAXSTR);

    scanf(format, str);

    scanf("%*[^\n]");
    scanf("%*c");

    return str;
}
```

If there is something I left out in my explanation ask me in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Use debugger to find out  where it fails.

Comment: Segmention faults are caused by reading something pointed to by a pointer... when that pointer has not been properly set it.

Answer (score 0):

You dereferenced `room` which is NULL in the line `if(PutGuestInsideList(room->room.list) == false)`. You can not dereference a NULL pointer. The `room` pointer should be properly set in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` :

```
    int main()
    {
    Reservations* room = NULL;//here you initialise pointer with NULL
    List list = { NULL };

    printf("New guest: \n");
    if(PutGuestInsideList(room->room.list) == false)// and here you try to access it
        printf("Try again. \n");


}
```

At `if` statement you are accessing member `room.list` on pointer `room` even if `room` is `NULL`.

BTW: Use (or learn to use) debugger, you will be able to debug your programs faster.(that's why they are called debuggers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to spend some time on google looking up tutorials on pointers in C.  As others are pointing out, room is set to null but you dereference it.

```
Reservations* room = NULL;
// and then
if(PutGuestInsideList(room->room.list) == false)
```

you also need to review these lines:

```
EnterString(newpers->person.name);
EnterString(newpers->person.surname);
```

Neither `person.name` nor `person.name` is given a buffer to write in. They are pointers which do not point anywhere but you attempt to use them.